# Background pattern repeat on table row

Tags: css, design-patterns, background, row

I'm having trouble with settings a pattern-base background on a table-row. On this screenshot you can see that in-between the cell, the background has some kind of position glitch, which is strange because the CSS is applied on the `table-row` and not the `table-cell`.

[image]
Here a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qzo9hrz8/3/

Comment: Post the relevant html and css.

Comment: Added in the question

Comment: I use this bugger for that: http://www.stripegenerator.com/. The issue is the image for the pattern and how the lines align and also the size of the image not the css

Comment: No it's definitly a layout/css problem, I've updated the jsfiddle to show you differences

Answer (score 0):

The problem is tr tag cannot have most of the css properties including background property. This leads your background applied on tr to td automatically, instead of tr theoretically.

Here I have a solution, making use of colspan where you want to use the background.

```
[Check out the solution in jsfiddle][1]
```

Comment: I can't see any jsfiddle?

Comment: Not sure why the link is not showing, here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/surajpasa/uxfvuon/

Comment: Hoo I see, that would be nice if that didn't require to change the html that much.

Comment: Ok I have updated the fiddle, you can see the below table. The idea is to put the pattern background in whole table. The row in which you don't want pattern, just put another solid color.
Hope this helps.